# Perl CGI - Pass variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

I have the below Perl Code:

```
$USERID = $ENV{REMOTE_USER};
```

A button:

```
<input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Refresh Book Ref Data" onclick='myFunction()'>
```

And the below JavaScript Function:

```
function myFunction() {
    var password = prompt("Please Enter Unix Password");
    document.getElementById("pwvalue").value = password;
}
```

I want to Pass the $USERID variable into the JavaScript Function so I can put:

```
var password = prompt("Please Enter Unix Password for User" + $USERID);
```

Comment: Where is your HTML/JS generated? Does the same Perl program that contains the `$USERID = $ENV...` line also output the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this - >

```
myFunction('$USERID')
```

And the method should me something like this ->

```
function myFunction(my_var){
...
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/cdwagydf/ - I can't seem to get this to work, please try with this example

Comment: I don't see you are passing the variable to your function. Please pass the variable to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes

```
var password = prompt("Please Enter Unix Password for User" + "$USERID");
```

**Explanation**

Suppose `$USERID` have some data for example `someid`. You have use the `$USERID` into javascript, it means it will works as follow

```
var password = prompt("Please Enter Unix Password for User" + someid);
```

Here javascript will consider `someid` is a javascript variable, but actually `someid` was data not a variable so use quotes.

**If you working with javascript means fix the errors using console.log or console in your browser.**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/cdwagydf/ - I can't seem to get this to work, please try with this example